# Modifying A TextBlock.Text Of A Page From A Window

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to change the text for the TextBlock in the Window. I keep getting the NullRefernceException. How do I fix this?

Welcome.xaml

```
        <TextBlock x:Name="StartNotice" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="247,252,0,0"   
        TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.595,0.627"   
        Text="Say &quot;abracadabra&quot; to start ." FontStyle="Italic" 
        TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Purple" Width="150"/>
```

Welcome.xaml.cs

```
        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow=new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.DataContext=this;
            mainWindow.Show();    
        }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
        try
        {
            myKinect=KinectSensor.KinectSensor[0]; 
        }
        catch
        {
            Welcome welcomePage=(Welcome)this.DataContext();
            welcomePage.StartNotice.Text="Please connect a Kinect";
        }
```

Comment: Welcome welcomePage=(Welcome)this.DataContext;

Comment: Tried removing the parens from DataContext. Still throws exception: NullReferenceException was unhandled...Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the exception to be thrown?  Have you inspected the welcomePage object in MainWindow.xaml.cs from the debugger?

Comment: What's the structure of your application?  I'm wondering why when the Welcome Page loads you create a MainWindow and then set the mainWindows datacontext to the page before showing the mainWindow.  What object hosts the page? What/how is the code in MainWindow.xaml.cs being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for not responding responsively. The solution I have implemented is described below:

The structure of my application is:

**Window** - MainWindow
**Pages** - Welcome, Login, Menu, Task

Pages are loaded using navigate to Function:

```
private void navigateTo(Page page) {this.Content=page;} // <this> is MainWindow
```

So in other pages the MainWindow is passed in the constructor for the page to access its members without creating another instance of MainWindow (especially navigateTo(), since all pages are created in MainWindow class.)

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
Welcome welcomePage;

public MainWindow() {...welcomePage = new Welcome(this);}
```

Welcome.xaml.cs

```
MainWindow mainWindow;

public Welcome(MainWindow windowMain)
{
    mainWindow=windowMain;
}
```

To change the content of StartNotice it was as simple as:

```
setupKinect()
{
...StartNotice.Text="Please connect a Kinect";... //used in a try-catch block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties of the control can be easily modified using MVVM pattern. An alternative and a much better way would be to change it through view model.

Comment: I will look more into the MVVM pattern. Started with a tutorial from Channel9, MVVM DevReady, but i'm short on time to complete a project while being new to C#, .NET, WPF, and having to program the Kinect with its developing documentation. This applicaiton will be very short, mostly focusing on KinectInteractions and speech recognition with a integration of data from a RTLS.

Answer (score 0):

I am just wondering where did you try to change the text of the "StartNotice"?..Because as far as i seen, there is nothing like defining the StartNotice.text in your try{} block.

Comment: I disconnected the Kinect in order to cause the catch block to initiate. If I place a MessageBox.Show() instead of trying to change welcomePage.StartNotice.Text, everything is fine.

Comment: Since you are just assigning the value, you may try this code.

Welcome welcomePage=new Welcome();
welcomePage.StartNotice.Text="Please connect a Kinect";